# Send Angular API GET request value to a variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, get

I am trying to display the data of an object on Angular like so
`{{myCharactere && myCharactere.statistics && myCharactere.statistics[stat.key] || ''}}`.
The object is issue from an API GET request but I'm not able to send it's value to my local variable myCharactere. Thank you for helping me out! Edit: Added code for clarification

Here is what I tried

TypeScript component

```
export class StatsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  myCharactere: any;
  statLookup = [
    // Pourquoi est-ce un mauvais choix???
    { key: 'str', prefix: $localize`str`, suffix: $localize`enght`, couleur: 'bg-danger' },
    { key: 'dex', prefix: $localize`dex`, suffix: $localize`terity`, couleur: 'bg-primary' },
    { key: 'con', prefix: $localize`con`, suffix: $localize`stitution`, couleur: 'bg-warning' },
    { key: 'int', prefix: $localize`int`, suffix: $localize`elligence`, couleur: 'bg-success' },
    { key: 'sag', prefix: $localize`wis`, suffix: $localize`dom`, couleur: 'bg-info' },
    { key: 'cha', prefix: $localize`cha`, suffix: $localize`risma`, couleur: 'bg-dark' }
  ];
  constructor(public myService: ServeurService) { }



    ngOnInit(): void {
this.myService.getAllInfosById(this.myService.getPersonnageIdByName("Xefoul Snaromers")).subscribe(result => {
    this.myCharactere = result
    console.log(this.myCharactere);
   });
      
      getModifier(stat: number): string {
        const mod = Math.floor((stat-10)/2)
        return (mod<0)?'-':'+'+ mod.toString();
      }
    }
```

TypeScript Service

```
export class ServeurService {
  
  personnages: any[] = [];
  persoName = '';

  constructor(private http_client: HttpClient) { }

 
  getPersonnage(): Observable<ICharactere[]> {
    return this.http_client.get<ICharactere[]>(this.serverCharacter).pipe(retry(4));
  }

  getAllInfosById(id: string) {
    const myUrl = 'https://cegep.fdtt.space/v1/character/' + id;
    return this.http_client.get<ICharactere>(myUrl).pipe();
  }

  setPersonnageName(name: string) {
    this.persoName = name;
  }

  getPersonnageName():string {
    return this.persoName;
  }

  getPersonnages() {
    this.http_client.get<any>('https://cegep.fdtt.space/v1/characters').subscribe({
      next: (val) => {
        val.data.forEach((element: { data: any; }) => {
        this.personnages.push(element);
        });
      }
    });
    return this.personnages;
  }

  getPersonnageById(id: string) {
    const persoSelectionne = this.getPersonnages().find((x: { id: string; }) => x.id === id);
    return persoSelectionne;
  }

  getPersonnageIdByName(name: string) {
    const persoSelectionne = this.getPersonnages().find((n: {name: string; }) => n.name === name);
    console.log("perso name service", persoSelectionne)
    return persoSelectionne.id; 
  }
}
```

HTML to display

```
<div class="row text-center text-light bg-secondary mt-2  bg-transparent">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-2" *ngFor="let stat of statLookup">
            <div class="{{stat.couleur}} mx-xxl-4 mx-2 mx-md-1 rounded-4">
                <div class="fw-bold">{{stat.prefix}}<span class="d-none d-lg-inline">{{stat.suffix}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="h2">
                    {{myCharactere && myCharactere.statistics && myCharactere.statistics[stat.key] ? getModifier(myCharactere.statistics[stat.key]) : ''}}
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    {{myCharactere && myCharactere.statistics && myCharactere.statistics[stat.key] || ''}}
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model if it helps

```
export interface ICharactere {
    error: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    statistics: { [ key : string ]: number }
    race: string;
    player: string;
    classe : string;
    sousclasses: string;
    level: number;
    background: string;
    synopsis: string;
    image: string;
    health: number;
    currentHealth: number;
    traits: {
        trait: string;
        description: string;
    }[];
    armorClass: number;
    initiative: number;
    speed: number;
}
```

Comment: This should work fine. Have you tried to call `getAllInfosById("demochar").subscribe(console.log)` from a component? You should now be able to see the response in your console. One note: using `.pipe()` is not necessary, if you don't include any operators in your pipe.

Comment: You're right it does! I was chasing the wrong mistake then... I'm trying to declare a variable with the value of  getAllInfosById so I can display the informations in HTML like {{ myVariable.name }} for example. Do you know how by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

Summarized from comments:

In your component you can use

```
serviceName.getAllInfosById("demochar").subscribe(console.log)
```

to manually make the request to the API and log the result. Please be aware that `this.http_client.get<ICharactere>(myUrl)` returns a cold observable. This means that nothing will be done until you actually call `.subscribe` to it.

**Best practice:**
Usually when you want to display data from an observable in your HTML template you define an observable and subscribe to it using `async` pipe.

The way to do this is to first define the observable in your component, like: `info$ = this.serviceName.getAllInfosById("demochar")`.

Now in your HTML template you can use `{{ (info$ | async).name }}` to first subscribe to the observable (`async` pipe does this for you) and display the `name` property of the emitted value.

Comment: I get a "No overload matches this call" error when I implement {{ (info$ | async).name }}

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using? Usually this error appears when you don't have an observable but still try to subscribe to it using `async` pipe.

Comment: I just updated the code. Thank you for looking into it !

Comment: Well, this is a different approach than my proposed approach since you are handling the subscription yourself in the component. What error do you get there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually using an observable like `this.http_client.get<ICharactere>(myUrl)`, another way is to await the return value and store it in a `this.myCharactere`:

```
async getInfos(): void {
   this.myCharactere = await firstValueFrom(this.myService.getAllInfosById(this.myService.getIdPersonnageByName("Xefoul Snaromers")));
}
```